# setup.py "nice to have" dependency modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, distutils, leveldb

I'm looking at a setup.py file that looks a bit like this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys

if sys.argv[1] == 'test':
    import multiprocessing, logging
    from billiard import util

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

if sys.version_info < (2, 7, 0):
    required.append('importlib')

setup(
    version='0.1',
    name='...',
    description='...',
    author='...',
    author_email='...',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={},
    install_requires=required,
    include_package_data=True,
    tests_require=[
        'billiard',
        'nose==1.3'
    ],
    test_suite='nose.collector'
)
```

I am trying to install the module on windows. It would appear that the module has been developed on another OS as it fails to compile one of the modules (`leveldb`) in `requirements.txt`.

Looking at the code, it looks like it might work without `leveldb` (though perhaps with poorer performance). **Is there any easy way to change the status of the `leveldb` library so its failure to install doesn't stop the main module from installing?**

Clearly I could remove the dependency from requirements.txt, but I'm considering how the libary might be edited to accomodate windows.

Comment: "Who" requires `leveldb`? Is it `billiard`? `nose`? If so, try changing the code in their `setup.py`.

Comment: @WilliamFernandes `leveldb` is listed in the requirements.txt

Comment: @WilliamFernandes This is the actual file I'm looking at: https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/blob/develop/setup.py (fails on windows due to leveldb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare optional dependencies as [extras in your setup.py](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies)